# bluemix single sign on login error

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to code for the process to logout of Single Sign On and I'm getting this error when creating the service -

FBTIAS006E An error occurred during the login process.

```
Time:2016/08/01 14:45:17
Request address:/mtfim/sps/idaas/auth/openid/callback
Error details:FBTIAS006E An error occurred during the login process.
```

I've tried this multiple times this afternoon and have cleared my cache and cookies.

This is in the US South region.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work after deleting a Single Sign on service I had in another space.  This is a trial account so I may have hit the limit of the number of services/applications allowed.